# Insert and select query.... Aggregate data in multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a specific requirement in oracle where I have the following data in table1. I need to sum the values in column3 of table1 that has the same No and date and insert the data as shown in table2.

Is there a way where I can use insert and select in a query to achieve this requirement?

Table1

```
1 | 5/7/2013  | 10
1 | 5/7/2013  | 30
1 | 5/7/2013  | 50
1 | 6/28/2015 | 5
1 | 6/28/2015 | 70
1 | 6/28/2015 | 10
2 | 1/9/2016  | 60
2 | 1/9/2016  | 70
2 | 1/9/2016  | 80
```

Table 2

```
1 | 5/7/2013  | 90
1 | 6/28/2015 | 85
2 | 1/9/2016  | 210
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` with `SUM`.  Have you tried a query yet?  The best way to learn SQL is to practice using it.

Comment: Ygla it is a **requirement** for you to show us what query you have tried to use, it might not be complete or correct - e.g. `create table new_table2 as select col1, col2, sum(col3) sum_col3 from old_table1 group by col1, col2` but then we can assist. In the footnote of this page is a Help link, there you will find tips on how to ask questions (so that you get prompt answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example.

```
create table c_table (
    c1 number,
    c2 DATE,
    c3 number);

create table c_table_2 (
    b1 number,
    b2 DATE,
    b3 number
);

insert into c_table values (1, to_date('5/7/2013', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 10);
insert into c_table values (1, to_date('5/7/2013', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 50);
insert into c_table values (1, to_date('6/28/2015', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 5);
insert into c_table values (1, to_date('6/28/2015', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 70);
insert into c_table values (1, to_date('6/28/2015', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 10);
insert into c_table values (2, to_date('1/9/2016', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 60);
insert into c_table values (2, to_date('1/9/2016', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 70);
insert into c_table values (2, to_date('1/9/2016', 'MM/dd/YYYY'), 80);

commit;

insert into c_table_2 select c1, c2, sum(c3) from c_table group by c1, c2;

commit;

select * from c_table_2;
```

[image]

Please, let me know if this works for you